# send a input String from JPanel 1 to JPanel2

Tags: java, string, swing, jpanel

i have 2 jpanel(panel1 and panel2),and i want  send a input string from panel1 to 2, but how?In few words In panel2 there will be buttons (yes or no) and at the press i want to send the response `response="Yes"||"No"` to panel1.I've try to create an object of panel2 but when i send the variable,response is null.Can you explain me using java swing?

Comment: There lots of ways you can do this, typically though, you need a reference to the object you want to talk to

Comment: i do a object, but when i go to control the content of variable, response is null.can you write me some example?

Comment: You can? Next time, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: sorry,simply i do what i wrote first